# How do I make a layout occupy 1/2 the screen?

Tags: android, layout

I'm curious what I need to do if I want a layout to occupy the right side of the screen, regardless of screen size.

Do I have to put some empty element with a weight of 1 as the left side? Or is it possible to just specify that a layout align itself with the right side of its parent and take up some percentage? And if so... how?  Ideally the parent is a RelativeLayout, but I'll work with whatever solution works cause at present everything I've tried results in something entirely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only solution is to have a weighted `LinearLayout`. The view's weight divided by the layout weightSum represents the percentage of the *free space* on the screen.

You can make it have two child views with each width set to 0dp and weight set to 1.

Weighted layouts work in two phases: The first phase measures the `layout_width` of each view. The second phase distributes any remaining space (total layout width - accumulated sum of each view's width) regarding the `layout_weight` / `weightSum` relation.

Comment: wait, you're saying I should set the layout_width to 0dp and it will still occupy space on the screen?? But that aside, if the parent has a weightSum of 2, I would put an empty layout on the left and my intended layout on the right and give them each a weight of 1, right?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Indeed, as the weight contributes to the view's width. In fact if you were to set the width to something other than 0dp you wouldn't get half the screen space, just half the available space (screen space minus said width).

Comment: Ok, I'm totally confused. Let's say the screen had 100 total and I set the left to 0dp and its weight to 1, wouldn't (logically) the available space *still be 100dp, as the left side isn't actually using any space... I think I'm missing something really fundamental here.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: What you said sounds about right. Weighted layouts work in two phases. The first phase measures the `layout_width` of each view. The second phase distributes any remaining space (total layout width - accumulated sum of each view's width) regarding the `layout_weight` / `weightSum` relation.

Comment: I see... so, once its figured out that neither view takes up any space it then grants them 1/2 the available space each... very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

To make an element align to any side, you should set the gravity of it's parent element (probably the layout that contains the element). Of course, in your case, set the **"gravity"** attribute of the linear layout to **right**. You might also need to change the layout's **"orientation"** to **horizontal**

For making it take only half of the screen, set the **"weight sum"** of the parent layout and and **"layout weight"** of the children. The sum of the weights of the children should equal to the weight sum of the parent.